# Enable No-Execute Protection in my BIOS on Aspire One 753

Tags: bios, acer-aspire-one

I am trying to install Windows 8 on Virtualbox, so I need to turn on No-Execute memory protection for it to work, according to this article: [Windows 8 on VirtualBox and VMWare: Your PC Needs To Restart Fix](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/26800/windows-8-on-virtualbox-and-vmware-your-pc-needs-to-restart-fix/)

I tried going into the BIOS and I can't find any options related to *No execute Memory Protection*. *HAV* is already enabled, but it is still not in the BIOS.

Here is some info:

```
OS Name Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise
Version 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
Other OS Description    Not Available
System Manufacturer Acer
System Model    Aspire One 753
System Type x64-based PC
Processor   Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU        U3600  @ 1.20GHz, 1199 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 2 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date   INSYDE V1.29, 8/12/2011
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 4.00 GB
Total Physical Memory   3.68 GB
Available Physical Memory   2.09 GB
Total Virtual Memory    7.35 GB
Available Virtual Memory    4.41 GB
```

Comment: I am confused by your title -- do you want to turn off the `NX` protection for the virtual machine?  What does that have to do with Windows 8?

Comment: [http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/26800/windows-8-on-virtualbox-and-vmware-your-pc-needs-to-restart-fix/]

Comment: Please change "disable" to "enable"

Comment: Oops sorry.  By the way, you can edit the question if you want to change something.

Comment: Try this `wmic` command from here:  http://serverfault.com/questions/181839/how-to-detect-nx-xd-bit-under-windows  If it comes back with TRUE, then you have it enabled already.

Comment: It says "False"